# Newest Laptops in Ubuntu Certified hardware list?

Tags: 14.04, hardware, lenovo, hardware-certification

I am looking for a new laptop, with the intent to run Ubuntu Linux on it. 
I have a preference for Lenovo, but Asus is good too. So I started looking at the [Ubuntu Certified hardware list](http://www.ubuntu.com/certification/desktop/models/?release=14.04%20LTS&category=Laptop) but then I realized that page doesn’t really help me shop for a New laptop. I cant tell when the laptops came out, if they are new or old, and I see no way to search the certified hardware list for specific hardware details (like CPU speed, RAM, weight, size, networking options, etc...) which would interest me when trying to buy a new laptop with Ubuntu certified hardware. Is there a better site? Is there a sorting mechanism I am missing?

I am not asking for Prices or for specific vendors. What I am asking, is how I use the list of Ubuntu certified Hardware, in the objective sense, for getting a new laptop.

For a little more detail, I have about 500$-600$ for this, which puts me out of business for getting a system76 machine.

Answer (score 2):

See latest probes of Ubuntu-powered laptops in this list: https://linux-hardware.org/?view=timeline

Example probe: https://linux-hardware.org/?probe=16e0fe515b

You can find manufacture year in the Host Info section of a probe. Also take a look at the Linux kernel version used.

Search for a computer by vendor and model: https://linux-hardware.org/index.php?view=search_computer&computer_vendor=Lenovo&computer_model=G570&computer_type=notebook

[image]

I'm the author of this project, feel free to ask any questions!

Enjoy!

Comment: It seems that this is a link to your own site, so this information may be relevant : https://askubuntu.com/help/promotion.

Comment: It's a project that is common to all Linux distributions: https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Hardware_probe  ,  https://fedoraproject.org/wiki/Hardware_probe  ,  https://wiki.gentoo.org/wiki/Hw-probe